# php random generator table represent my lab result

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

How to use php random generator table represent my lab result.
Pass and fail random position show on table. 
just want to input `Pass = 13` and `Fail = 3`   two number.

```
Test1   P   Test5   P   Test9   F   Test13  P
Test2   P   Test6   P   Test10  F   Test14  P
Test3   P   Test7   P   Test11  P   Test15  P
Test4   F   Test8   P   Test12  P   Test16  P
```

[image]

thank you!

Comment: Hello, Welcome to the SO. Your question is not clear for me, so please can you provide more detail what you want?

Comment: Is your lab result is an array or not? If yes, in wich format?*

Comment: my test result just record 16 times. maybe 12 times pass, 4 times fail. or 14 pass 2 fail.

Comment: If you want a clear answer, you should at least tell what kind of data do you want to display. Is it an array? a dynamic ajax response? a simple string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```php
<?php

function random_swap_array($array, $scale=10) {
        $max = sizeof($array) - 1;
        for ($i=0; $i<$scale; $i++) {
                $pos1 = random_int(0, $max);
                $pos2 = random_int(0, $max);

                // swap the value of 2 pos
                $tmp = $array[$pos2];
                $array[$pos2] = $array[$pos1];
                $array[$pos1] = $tmp;
        }
        return $array;
}

function gen_n(int $n, $value) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) yield $value;
}

function gen_prefix_num(int $n, $prefix) {
        for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) yield "{$prefix}{$i}";
}

// This generates an assoc array with key "Test1" to "Test18"
// and values of randomly placed 14 "P" and 4 "F"
$arr = array_combine(
        iterator_to_array(gen_prefix_num(18, 'Test')),
        random_swap_array(array_merge(
                iterator_to_array(gen_n(4, 'F')),
                iterator_to_array(gen_n(14, 'P'))
        ), 100)
);
var_dump($arr); // display results
```

Result:

```
array(18) {
  ["Test1"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test2"]=>
  string(1) "F"
  ["Test3"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test4"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test5"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test6"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test7"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test8"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test9"]=>
  string(1) "F"
  ["Test10"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test11"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test12"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test13"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test14"]=>
  string(1) "F"
  ["Test15"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test16"]=>
  string(1) "P"
  ["Test17"]=>
  string(1) "F"
  ["Test18"]=>
  string(1) "P"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's so great